# Sorting in mongo according to number of occurences

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to implement "Popular Keyword" in my web app so that most searched keywords will show there.. For that i have created a db in mongo. I need to retrieve data from mongo so that mostly occuring keywords should sort and should return to my page. In sql it is just like as,
`select names,count(names) from keyword_db group by names order by names;`

need both java code and mongo shell query..

Comment: Try to look at Mongodb Aggregation Framework (new in Mongodb 2.1)

Comment: @SergeyGavruk thnx fr the respnse. i did.. i didnt find nything from there.

Comment: try to look at `$group` and `$sort` operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try for the mongo shell query (I'm sorting in descending order:

```
db.keyword_db.aggregate ( [ 
   { $group: { _id: "$names", count: { $sum: 1 } } }, 
   { $sort: { count: -1 } }  ] )
```

For the Java version:

```
    DBCollection myColl = db.getCollection("keyword_db"); 

    // for the $group operator
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$names");
    groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));

    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );

    // for the $sort operator

    DBObject sortFields = new BasicDBObject("count", -1);

    DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", sortFields );

    // run the aggregation

    AggregationOutput output = myColl.aggregate(group, sort);

    System.out.println( output.getCommandResult() );
```

The following page may help you also:
   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Comment: Thnx fr the respnse. I have tested in shell , its showing that aggregate is not a function. also problem for $group. Does it depends on mongodb version.

Comment: Yes, I was using version 2.2.  You need at least version 2.1.

Comment: As for  the java driver, you need at least the Version 2.9.0 of the Java driver.

Answer (score 1):

For sorting you can use following..1 for ascending and -1 for desc.

```
db.keyword_db.find( { names: "A" } ).sort( { user_id: 1 } )
```

and for groupBy You can use Aggregation framework..

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/